# result of this integral? $\int_{|z|=3} \frac{e^z}{(z-1)(z-2)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I think I can solve it by taking:
$z(t)=3(\cos t + i \sin t)=3e^{it}$
and by using

$$\int_c f(z)dz = \int_c \frac{dz}{dt}\cdot f(z(t))$$
we have:

$\displaystyle\int_{|z|=3} \frac{e^{3e^{it}}}{(3e^{it}-1)(3e^{it}-2)}\cdot3ie^{it}$
but I can't continue this approach to find a solution without using residue theorem

Comment: The solution is pretty trivial using the residue theorem. Is that tool available to you at this point in your coursework?

Comment: no; indeed I should solve it without residue theorem

Comment: I have doubts concerning the equality $e^{it}=(\sin t+i \cos t)$. Should it not be $e^{it}=(\cos t + i \sin t)$ or am I missing something?

Comment: you are right I have a typing mistake unfortunately

Comment: The second and third integral should involve a $dt$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)}=\frac{1}{z-2}-\frac{1}{z-1}$$

Thus
$$\int_{|z|=3} \frac{e^z}{(z-1)(z-2)}dz=\int_{|z|=3} \frac{e^z}{z-2}dz-\int_{|z|=3} \frac{e^z}{z-1}dz$$

The answer follows easily from Cauchy Integral Formula.

Comment: thank you.I got the answer using your hint

Comment: @mohamadreza Then accept his answer to show that it helped you `^^`